# Quick question on conditions for Jordan canonical form

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

just a quick question about how to determine if a matrix has a JCF - I know that if the characteristic polynomial factorises as a product of linear factors it has one but what if you only know the minimal polynomial factorises as a product of linear factors? Is this enough to say the matrix has a JCF? Thanks

Comment: These two conditions are equivalent. The characteristic and minimal polynomial have the same irreducible factors.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

Comment: Oh yeah that makes sense. Thanks